# How to show message in popup window while python script is running

Tags: python

Is there any way to show the message in popup window that process is running when python script start and disappear the popup window when process is done. Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of message do you think about? Some text status in terminal? Some popup window?

Comment: pop up window show that the process is running

Comment: I would use [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) for this, it should be shipped with your Python.

Comment: Thank you i will try to use tkinter

Answer (score 4):

A very flexible method you could look into is creating a tkinter window:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

def some_function():
    print('Do stuff')
    time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create window
    window = tk.Tk()

    # Create label
    label_var = tk.StringVar()
    label_var.set('Program is running...')
    label = tk.Label(window, textvariable=label_var)
    label.pack()

    # Update and show window once
    window.update_idletasks()
    window.update()

    # Your function code
    some_function()

    # Get rid of window
    window.destroy()
```

Edit: just saw someone answered with tkinter in the comments... will leave this here as an example